# How to find out correlation between Attributes in R

Tags: r, data-mining, correlation

I am new at R.

I have a large data set which has many numeric and non numeric columns.

I am trying to find out which of the columns are highly correlated and this  correlation is meaningfull or not.

First I want to find out correlation between numeric values and then categorical values. It should be separate from each other.
What should I do to find out correlation?

And how to determine errors or unusual datas in dataset?

This is just an example dataset ;

```
 > df1 <- LungCapData22
 > sapply(df1,class)
 LungCap       Age    Height     Smoke    Gender Caesarean 
"numeric" "integer" "numeric"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"


      LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean
1    6.475   6   62.1    no   male        no
2    10.125  18   74.7   yes female        no
3     9.550  16   69.7    no female       yes
4    11.125  14   71.0    no   male        no
```

Comment: Have you already tried the `cor()` and `cor.test()` functions?

Comment: Getting error below cor(df.train$LotFrontage,df.train$LotArea use="complete.obs", method="kendall") 
Error: unexpected symbol in "cor(df.train$LotFrontage,df.train$LotArea use"

Comment: That error is because a missing comma in your call. Try the following.
`cor(df.train$LotFrontage, df.train$LotArea, use = "complete.obs", method = "kendall")`

Comment: It works. Thank you @Juan Bosco